# Extend MultiDexApplication in MyApp class

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, android-multidex

First of all, I was trying to create the class App that extends MultiDexApplication, like this :

```
public class App extends MultiDexApplication {

    private static Application application;

    public static Application getApplication() {
        return application;
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return getApplication().getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        application = this;
    }

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(getContext());
    }

}
```

But i was getting a message advising :

```
The <application> com.packageName.App is not registered in the manifest less... (Ctrl+F1)
```

[image: warning]

The documentation tells nothing about it.

So, how can I register it at manifest if it's already have the name writed?

```
 <application 
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        ...
```

By [this docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#mdex-gradle), I simply stopped to use this named application given and use : `android:name=".App"`

And this is the class App created :

```
public class App extends Application {

    private static Application application;

    public static Application getApplication() {
        return application;
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return getApplication().getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        application = this;
        MultiDex.install(getContext());
    }

}
```

Note that I'm calling `MultiDex.install(this);` at onCreate

Is this the corresponding method discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53314675/whats-the-difference-between-extending-multidexapplication-and-multidex-install) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you have to inherit `MultiDexApplication`. So you have your `App` class, you call `MultiDex.install`, you have your app class under `<application/>` tag in your manifest (full path or relative path - does not matter).

Please also make sure your app module's build.gradle file has `multiDexEnabled true` under android/defaultConfig ?

PS.: typical (relative path) way to specify App under manifest:

```
    <application
        android:name=".App"
```

Comment: Yes, everything is ok at gradle config. I'm just wondering if the App class that I done is the correct approach. I saw the Multidex class that extends Application and there is a method called `attachBaseContext` and the class have an empty constructor... None of this things I did at App class (as my ask shows the code in the end).

Comment: In my opinion your approach to defining App for your multidex application is correct. Here is what I'm using:

`public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);

        if (!BuildConfig.TESTMODE) {
            MultiDex.install(this);
        }
    }
}`

Comment: There is difference between call Multidex install at onCreate and attachBaseContext ?

Comment: Yes. attachBaseContext will be called before onCreate for your application instance.

Comment: Actually, there is alternative example at the end of https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex - but key idea is to call install before any actual work happens. In other words as soon as possible @MarcelloCâmara

Comment: You mean the part of "Test Multidex Apps" ?  I really didn't see it. But I think it mean to use Junit. getTargetContext() can't be called at App class, and onCreate has no Bundle args. I'll keep what I have done... I think it's correct. I've done some tests and nothing wrong/crashed

Comment: I've changed the call into attachBaseContext because my 14° test crashes saying that `application = this;` was null.